# Reloading url in browser in a React app using Redux and React Router causing store state to be undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am using create-react-app with react-redux and react-router.

`<SingleProduct />` is defined as such

```
function SingleProduct(props){
let id=  props.match.params.id
let products = props.products
return (display the matching product properties)
}
```

When `<SingleProduct />` is rendering, it is relying on the id received through routing.
It then searches for the id inside `props.products` to get that specific product properties. 
`<SingleProduct />` is connected to redux store like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
return {
products: state.products}
}
```

When I refresh the browser, `props.products` is not recognized anymore and I get errors of trying to read properties of undefined.

How can I solve this problem? Is it a routing problem (client-side-routing) or something else? I ejected my app, tried to adjust Webpack configuration to solve the client-side-routing but it didn't work out. 
Please note that I am fetching the products through REST API. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the exact error? you probably just need to check if `props.products` exists before trying to access properties on it. not sure if you thought state was going to persist across page refreshes, but it does not without using some storage mechanism like localStorage

Comment: also, welcome to stackoverflow! it's always better if you take the time for format your code in questions. for instance, you're missing a closing curly brace in `mapStateToProps`. presumably that's not in your actual code otherwise it wouldn't compile. please edit your question to fix it up

Comment: @azium code fixed. thanks. Yes I didn't know state doesn't persist on refresh and I didn't come across this issue while reading React and redux tutorials and documentation. I am new to this and assembling all this puzzle is not always easy. Anyway I will look into it. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: @azium any insights about how to deal when u type the url directly in browser and state is not saved in localStorage. Like when you share a url (product) with someone. they press on it and the product page should load after having fetched the correct data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use localstorage or redux-persist in your project to keep stored state data after reload of url
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: Thanks. This solved part of my problem which is about reloading. However, the second part is about typing the url directly in the browser when the state is not already stored in local storage.